# Can't get Firebase data to display on simple Vue app

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, vuefire

I'm trying to get a simple Vue+Firebase app running that allows you to send strings to the firebase database and have the messages be displayed using the "v-for" directive. However, I keep getting the error

`Property or method "messages" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render`

even though I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct syntax based on Vue's example on their site and the Vuefire github page to link up `messages` to the database. I can push to the database just fine, but for some reason I can't read the data from the database. I've been unable to get this to work for about a day and at this point any help is appreciated.

Here is my code for reference:

index.html:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = { ... };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
     <div id="app">
      <input type="text" v-model="message" placeholder="Type a message!">
      <button v-on:click="sendData">Send Data</button>
      <br>
      <h3 v-for="msg in messages">{{msg.value}}</h3>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

app.js:

```
var messageRef = firebase.database().ref('local/responses');

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: ''
    }
  },
  firebase: function () {
    return {
      messages: messageRef
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendData: function () {
      messageRef.push(this.message);
      this.message = '';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Move your `messages` property from your `firebase:` property into the `data:` return object and you should be good

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't exactly solve the issue - when I move it to `data` I end up with a static number of `<h3>` tags, none of which display the value desired.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `messages` property in both the firestore return function as a database reference, as well as the data return function as an empty array for the database to bind to, as such.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: '',
      messages: []
    }
  },
  firebase: function () {
    return {
      messages: firebase.database().ref('local/responses')
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendData: function () {
      messageRef.push(this.message);
      this.message = '';
    }
  }
});
```

This happens because you're trying to bind the Firestore reference to a piece of data that doesn't exist within your Vue instance, it needs that empty array for it to bind to the data property.